# Phonegap cross-domain request fail on click but not at runtime

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

My PhoneGap's *"config.xml", "index.html"* files and my *server-side scripts* are set-up to allow CORS and everything works because my `$.ajax()` calls are performed with no errors when called at runtime.

I found that my `$.ajax()` calls are failing<sup>1</sup> and returning ***"An error occured: 0 error"*** only when performed on click because calling them at runtime they are returning the correct data with no errors, so could the problem be with the *click* event in *PhoneGap*? Here is my code:

```
$(".form-submit").click(function(e) {
    $(".ui-loader").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/app-scripts/search-flight.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { flight: $("#flightnumber").val() },
        success: /* Success function */,
        error: function(xhr) {alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);}
        });
    });
```

I really can't understand why when requesting AJAX at runtime it works correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/app-scripts/search-flight.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { flight: "KP 452B"},
        success: /* Success function */,
        error: function(xhr) {alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);}
        });
    });
```

Please help me, I'm at the final stages of this project and I want to go ahead with it.

---

<sup>1</sup> It only happens on **Android** and **iOS** and works correctly on **Windows Phone**.

Comment: And so, what error message do you get???

Comment: Is `$("#flightnumber").val()` returning expected value? Are you submiting a form by clicking `.form-submit`? This selector name supposes that yes and then you should prevent form to be submited in order to get your ajax request chance to complete

Comment: @A.Wolff `$("#flightnumber").val()` returns expected value. And yes, I'm submitting the form by clicking, everything works because on windoesPhone and on chrome it is ok. The fact is that the same request returns the correct data if performed inside the `$(document).ready()` (see first snippet) and failing if performed on click (see second snippet). I think there could be some problem with the click event in phonegap on android? Please help me, it is more than a week that I'm looking for a solution and I can not deal with it!!!!

Comment: Ok i'm not phonegap dev but if he form is submited then chance are your ajax request is aborted and so returns error. Why are you sending an ajax request while still submiting the form? If you need both behaviour, then my bet would be to try: `$.ajax({ context: $(this).closest('form')[0], ..., success: function(){this.submit();}});` And setting `e.preventDefault();` still inside click handler (not in any ajax callback)

Comment: I think I'll hang me by the neck. For design purposes which I don't know, some designer put the jquery mobile attribute `data-ajax="false"` in the form which tells jquery mob to submit the form as default and not using AJAX. Thank you @A.Wolff, your help guided me to the solution, I will post an answer explaining the solution and I will attribute your very helpfull effort, thank you again!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try ajax call with async: false & If your response is in JSON
 then use dataType: "json", OR "jsonp",

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/app-scripts/search-flight.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json", OR "jsonp",
        async: false,
        data: { flight: $("#flightnumber").val() },
        success: /* Success function */,
        error: function(xhr) {alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);}
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this but it was not the solution, anyway in this helped me a bit.